# Why do my previous dictionaries in a list change when I try to add a new one?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, append, key

I have a code that does the following:
Goes through a list of dictionaries, fills up a "temporary" dictionary with each one's data, and then appends the "temporary" dictionary to an "information" list.

However, I've noticed that every time the "temporary" dictionary changes, the overall "information" list changes as well.

This is a test code that perfectly represents the issue that I'm having:

```
dict1 = {"Name":"Maria", "Age":"22"}
dict2 = {"Name":"Ryley", "Age":"23"}
dict3 = {"Name":"Helen", "Age":"24"}

all_dicts = [dict1, dict2, dict3]

temp_dict ={}

info = []

for dict in all_dicts:
    print ("CURRENT DICT: " + dict["Name"])
    
    print ("Info before loop: " + str(info))
    #Temporary loop.
    for key in dict:
        temp_dict[key] = dict[key]
    print ("Info after loop: " + str(info))
    
    info.append(temp_dict)
```

When this is run, the "info" variable is different before and after the "temporary loop" despite the fact that it's the "temp_dict" variable that is changing. This is the output:

```
CURRENT DICT: Maria
Info before loop: []
Info after loop: []
CURRENT DICT: Ryley
Info before loop: [{'Name': 'Maria', 'Age': '22'}]
Info after loop: [{'Name': 'Ryley', 'Age': '23'}]
CURRENT DICT: Helen
Info before loop: [{'Name': 'Ryley', 'Age': '23'}, {'Name': 'Ryley', 'Age': '23'}]
Info after loop: [{'Name': 'Helen', 'Age': '24'}, {'Name': 'Helen', 'Age': '24'}]
```

I understand that the way to fix this would be to replace the "temporary loop" with this:

```
temp_dict = dict
```

But I would really like to understand why this is happening. The line above and the "temporary loop" should virtually be doing the same thing, so why is the "info" variable changing retroactively as the "temp_dict" variable does? Is there a way to prevent this besides my solution above?

Comment: because *they are all the same dict*. You keep appending *the same dict* to the `info` list

Comment: But if I append a dictionary to a list, and then later change that dictionary's information, the list should retain the original information of the dictionary, no?

Comment: @TheParable no it should not. A `dict` is mutable. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @TheParable - No. You appended a _reference_ to the dict to the list. But objects can have many references. And since all of those references point to the same object memory, a change via one reference is what will be seen by all references.

Comment: @TheParable *no*. It shouldn't. Because **it's the same dict**. Consider, `x = []; y = x; x.append(42); print(x,y)`

Comment: @Axe319 well, to be clear, "mutable" just means "exposes mutator methods", but the semantics of what appending to a list does is exactly the same between mutable and immutable types. Indeed, if you are willing to dig into implementation details, you *can* mutate immutable objects, and you'll see the same behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you create a single `temp_dict` outside of the loop and keep updating and appending that one dict to `info`. With each run of the temporary loop, you are changing the single dict that is referenced multiple times in the list.

The solution is to create `temp_dict` in the loop. You also print "Info after loop" *before* adding the dict to `info`, missing the data you just built up in the inner loop.

```
dict1 = {"Name":"Maria", "Age":"22"}
dict2 = {"Name":"Ryley", "Age":"23"}
dict3 = {"Name":"Helen", "Age":"24"}

all_dicts = [dict1, dict2, dict3]


info = []

for dict in all_dicts:
    temp_dict ={}
    print ("CURRENT DICT: " + dict["Name"])

    print ("Info before loop: " + str(info))
    #Temporary loop.
    for key in dict:
        temp_dict[key] = dict[key]

    info.append(temp_dict)
    print ("Info after loop: " + str(info))
```

outputs

```
CURRENT DICT: Maria
Info before loop: []
Info after loop: [{'Name': 'Maria', 'Age': '22'}]
CURRENT DICT: Ryley
Info before loop: [{'Name': 'Maria', 'Age': '22'}]
Info after loop: [{'Name': 'Maria', 'Age': '22'}, {'Name': 'Ryley', 'Age': '23'}]
CURRENT DICT: Helen
Info before loop: [{'Name': 'Maria', 'Age': '22'}, {'Name': 'Ryley', 'Age': '23'}]
Info after loop: [{'Name': 'Maria', 'Age': '22'}, {'Name': 'Ryley', 'Age': '23'}, {'Name': 'Helen', 'Age': '24'}]
```

To note, you can do this in fewer steps

```
dict1 = {"Name":"Maria", "Age":"22"}
dict2 = {"Name":"Ryley", "Age":"23"}
dict3 = {"Name":"Helen", "Age":"24"}

all_dicts = [dict1, dict2, dict3]

info = [d.copy() for d in all_dicts]
```

Comment: Interesting, and thank you. While this does solve it, and I do understand the logic behind it, I stil l don't quite understand why `temp_dict = dict` solves it as well. In theory, `temp_dict`  is still the same variable, just replaced with new info. Shouldn't I be having the same issue? Or is it because instead of changing the info, I am now referencing each dictionary individually?

Comment: If you do `temp_dict = dict` then they both reference the same object and Temporary Loop just copies the dict to itself. It "worked" because you are putting the original 3 unique dicts into info, but there was no copy to a new dict to fill `info`. Later changes to either the original dicts or those in `info` would have the same problem because no copy was made.

Answer (score 0):

It is the case of referencing a variable instead copying it. If you are not aware of it, it is like your new variable points to the old variable instead of making an independent copy, so whenever you make changes in the old variable because the new variable just points to the old one if you print it, it will show the changes however you haven't made any changes in new variable explicitly, to avoid this you have to make an actual copy of the old variable, in other words, it is known as 'Deep Copy' and referencing is known as 'shallow copy' you can read on it, it is language independent concept so no matter which language you are using it there almost in every programming language.

So here is a solution,
import the copy library

```
import copy
```

and change last line to

```
 info.append(copy.deepcopy(temp_dict))
```

here copy.deepcopy returns an independent copy of temp_dict so now you can change the temp_dict without changing the dict present in `info` array

Comment: The second question is why `temp_dict = dict` worked is because `dict` is itself a variable and not a copy so whenever you append it an actual variable gets stored in an array instead of a reference.

Comment: `deepcopy` is unnecessary here